# Should I put my GoogleApiClient.connect() in Activity.onCreate() instead of OnStart()

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an app that run at scheduled time.
So when my app start executing it won't be able to connect to Google since the `GoogleApiClient.connect()` is in the `Activity.onStart()` and just because the phone might be locked at that time.

So will it be a good idea to move the `GoogleApiClient.connect()`  to `Activity.onCreate()` ? Is there any other App design, you can suggest?

Thanks

Comment: It is a good practice to initialize variables in `onCreate`. Go read any Android tutorial.

Comment: You should really start with the example code Google gives you: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client

Comment: @JaredBurrows I totally understand it, but I have a  unique situation here. Such as the activity wont be able to connect and work unless the user unlocked the phone and brings up the app (to trigger `onStart()` event).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you app does, but maybe you should use a Service, not an Activity. With a Service you can handle some operations without a UI and you can of course use the GoogleApiClient too.

Answer (score 0):

The docs advise to put connect() in onStart() and disconnect in onStop(). This didnt work for me, so i put connect() in onCreate() and disconnect in onDestroy.

Everything has been working fine since i have done this. You might like to try it.